# How to pass different File paths to one autoit scripts using java

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

I have one scenario which i need upload a file from desktop window.

I am using autoit script.it is working fine when i hardcoded filepath in autoit script.

I have 100 scenarios to upload different files.so i need to write 100 autoit scripts.

can anyone help how to use one autoit script for all scenarios taking file path dyanmically using java,

Please anyone help to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may help to show your script and your attempt at using Java.  Also, how will Java know where the directories are?  Is this given via input?  Is it to loop through all directories under a specific directory?  Will there be a file which contains a list of all these directories?

Comment: Actually I am written below script

WinActivate("File Upload");
ControlSetText("File Upload", "", "Edit1", $aCmdLine[1] )
ControlClick("File Upload", "", "Button1").

and save as autoit.exe script and calling Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/autoifolder/"+autoit.exe")  in java

Comment: Post the script in the question section....it's a lot easier to read that way.  |=^]

Answer (score 2):

Use
$CmdLineRaw in the script.

Compile it and when you call that exe, do it like this

```
Run("CompiledScript.exe filepath")
```

Now your script will have 'filepath' stored in $CmdLineRaw

More on $CmdLineRaw in the Help File.

Comment: i have one doubt, in Run("CompiledScript.exe filepath") where we are justing giving path of the autoit script file but i want to give both autoit.exe file path and path of file to upload in java.how to give both paths daynamically using java

Comment: Run('CompiledScript.exe "filepath1" "filepath2"')
Then use $aCmdLine[1] and $aCmdLine[2]. Is that your problem?

Comment: There is no Run() method in java,we have Runtime.getRuntime.exec();

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime.exec("myCompiled.exe parameter1 parameter2");

Comment: and ofcourse dot forget to put parameters in their own quotes or you will get extra parameters if they have space in them.
eg. Runtime.getRuntime.exec('myCompiled.exe "parameter1" "parameter2"');

Comment: It is not accepting 3 parameters,if i declare Runtime.getRuntime("p1","p2","p3"); showing error:remove all parameters and declare parameter is string.

Comment: Who told you to put 3 parameters in there?
if you call run from ANY programming language or from a windows Run dialog, or from a shortcut like this "myCompiled.exe parameter1 parameter2"
that exe will receive those parameters.
Again, take a closer look and see the difference between your code and mine
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("myCompiled.exe parameter1 parameter2");
Runtime.getRuntime("p1","p2","p3");

Answer (score 0):

i have been trying to achieve the same, but the path of the file is read from an excel sheet and stored in a variable say "pfilepath".

Now i want to pass this variable as input to the autoIT script.

The code of autoIT script is as below ::

$FirefoxUpload = "File Upload"
$ChromeUpload = "Open"
Local $uploadWindow

If WinExists($FirefoxUpload) Then
  $uploadWindow = $FirefoxUpload
ElseIf WinExists($ChromeUpload) Then
  $uploadWindow = $ChromeUpload
EndIf

If ($uploadWindow) <> "" Then
  ControlFocus($uploadWindow,"","")
  Sleep(2000);
  ControlsetText($uploadWindow,"","",$CmdLineRaw)
  Sleep(2000);
  ControlClick($uploadWindow,"","Button1")
EndIf

Calling this autoIT compiled exe file in java program as ::

java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().ex
                    ("D:\Prathima\SectionOne_WS\SectionOne\File_to_Upload.exe "pfilepath" ");

But it throws an error "pfilepath. File not found"

Comment: Does this answer the question?